# Dynamically refer to a Terraform data resource by variable containing its name

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to concatenate a declared variable within the Terraform data assignation to build a dynamic call.

Having the following code:

```
# Policy 1
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "1_s3_access_policy" {
   statement {
     effect = "Allow"
     actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
     ]
     resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::1_s3_access_policy/*",
      "arn:aws:s3:::1_s3_access_policy",
     ]
     principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::67435677645:user/d2c-user-us-west-1"]
     }
   }
 }
# policy 2
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "2_s3_access_policy" {
    statement {
     effect = "Allow"
     actions = [
      "s3:GetObject",
      "s3:PutObject",
      "s3:DeleteObject",
     ]
     resources = [
      "arn:aws:s3:::2_s3_access_policy/*",
      "arn:aws:s3:::2_s3_access_policy",
     ]
     principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::67435677645:user/d2c-user-us-west-1"]
     }
   }
 }
# Policy 3
...
variable "s3_bucket_names" {
      type    = list(any)
      default = ["1_s3_access_policy", "2_s3_access_policy", "3_s3_access_policy"]
}

module "platform-cloud" {
      source              = "./module"
      count               = length(var.s3_bucket_names) //count will be 3
      bucket_name         = var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]
      sse_algorithm       = "aws:kms"
      iam_policy_document =  data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]}.json
}
```

It's failing with error:

`Error: Invalid character`

`on main.tf line 10, in module "platform-cloud":`

`iam_policy_document = data.aws_iam_policy_document.${var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]}.json`

`This character is not used within the language.`

Is there a way to concatenate a variable within **terraform data** call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform cannot dynamically look up a resource in the way you are attempting because that would mean that the resource dependency would not be decided until evaluation time, but Terraform needs to know the correct dependency order before evaluating any expressions.

However, you *can* meet your use-case of dynamically selecting a resource with the extra step of creating a mapping using the keys that you'll then use to select each one:

```
locals {
  bucket_policies = {
    s3_access_policy_1 = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_access_policy_1
    s3_access_policy_2 = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_access_policy_2
    s3_access_policy_3 = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_access_policy_3
  }
}

module "platform-cloud" {
  source = "./module"
  count  = length(var.s3_bucket_names) //count will be 3

  bucket_name         = var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]
  sse_algorithm       = "aws:kms"
  iam_policy_document = local.bucket_policies[var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]].json
}
```

I have changed the names of your data resources to be like `s3_access_policy_1` instead of `1_s3_access_policy` because Terraform does not allow resource names to start with digits. Terraform isn't reporting that error message yet because you have a syntax error, but resolving the syntax error would've then exposed the naming error.

Notice that now `module.platform-cloud`'s `iam_policy_document` refers to the whole of `local.bucket_policies`, which in turn depends on all three of the data resources. Terraform therefore understands that it must evaluate all three of those data resources before evaluating that module argument, which produces a correct evaluation order.

---

Although not directly related to your question, I'd recommend reading [When to use `for_each` instead of `count`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#when-to-use-for_each-instead-of-count) to decide whether it might be better to use [`for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) in your `module "platform-cloud"` block, instead of `count`.

Comment: Great approach!! just to need to modify ```data.aws_iam_policy_document``` instead of ```data.aws_iam_policy``` and it works just fine. Probably I mess a bit naming my buckets and policies code examples with digits but in real case the bucket names are different so just need to assign the correct name in the ***local bucket policies variable***. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would do this as follows:

```
iam_policy_document =  data.aws_iam_policy_document[var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]].json
```

Exact details would depend on how `data.aws_iam_policy_document` is defined. But sadly such information is not given in your question.

Comment: Syntax is correct, but `count` is going to be invalid here. Agree is not enough info for a "complete" answer.

Comment: I've edited and added my code with the data content. I've tried @Marcin comment above but it still failing.

Comment: ```iam_policy_document = data.aws_iam_policy_document[var.s3_bucket_names[count.index]].json

The "data" object must be followed by two attribute names: the data source
type and the resource name.```

Comment: @Sallyerik You can't do what you want. You have to fully refactor your `data.aws_iam_policy_document` definitions. i would suggest making new question dedicated to this new problem.

Comment: ```count``` works fine, with the ```var``` just wanted to point out the **resource name** of the data object. I think the content of the ```data``` object shouldn't add much value, does it?

Comment: @Sallyerik Sadly, you can't do this. `data.aws_iam_policy_document` must be created using for_each. Not separately as you do now. You have to refactor your code to make it work.